# Query string for custom data attribute

Tags: jquery, query-string, custom-data-attribute

This is how I hold my data in data-attribute:

```
<div class="playlist-item" data-video='[{"quality": "720p", "video": "video-url1"}, {"quality": "1280p", "video": "video-url2"}]'></div>
```

then with jquery when I want to get data-video attribute I say:

```
$('.playlist-item').data('video');
```

Now I am trying to do the same with query string parameters and I am wondering what would be the best way to write such query string for this part?

```
data-video='[{"quality": "720p", "video": "video-url1"}, {"quality": "1280p", "video": "video-url2"}]'
```

I am thinking of doing it like this:

```
?video=video-url1,video-url2&quality=720p,1280p
```

I am not generating html from query string, I will get this query string in javascript and use it. I know how to process query string, I am just asking for advice on how would be the best to construct such query string.

Would there be better way of achieving this?

Comment: Which language are you using to generate html?

Comment: I am not generating html from query string, I will get this query string in javascript and use it. I know how to process query string, I am just asking for advice on how would be the best to construct such query string.

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert on this, but I wrote this webscraper tool that scrapes sites based on what you search and I used the query string like this and it seemed to work out nicely:

```
mysite.com/search/keywords=blue+shirt&sort=price-high
```

and

```
mysite.com/search/keywords=blue+shirt&sort=newest
```

[Dribbble.com](https://dribbble.com/search/blue%20shirt) uses a similar structure

```
https://dribbble.com/search/blue%20shirt
```

Spaces are translated into `%20`, but if you replace a space with `+`, it does the same thing. I used the `+` to join the keywords.

> **[This article](https://www.compose.com/articles/using-query-string-queries-in-elasticsearch/) does a really good job of explaining the rules and
> what different symbols mean etc.**
> **And then, [Samantha Ming](https://www.samanthaming.com/) also wrote a [great article](https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/86-window-location-cheatsheet/) with a cheatsheet on how to construct these**

Your string I would probably write like this:

```
/video=video-url1+video-url2&quality=720p+1280p
```